# floppy disks only detected properly on same drive

Tags: linux, floppy

On Linux (Debian based): If I copy files onto a floppy disk in an external floppy drive and put this disk later into another floppy drive, the disk output is … interesting. An **excerpt**:

[image: scrambled output of healthy floppy disk's content]

- actual content is 5 files, the scrambled list contains way more (quit counting on "more than there should be")
- the disk isn't recognized properly
- filesystem's format is ext2, but the machine tries to mount as `vfat`
- manually specifying the filesystem's type doesn't work
- disk is okay, same results with different disks
- problem arises only between these two guys (external, USB Floppy drive vs. internal Floppy drive): The both just tread "their" disks properly

Back on the "original" drive, everything works properly.

And yes, I've tried mounting it manually.

**Question**: Where would you start looking for answers for this curious behaviour on the affected machine?

`dmesg` output on this:

```
Error: Error informing the kernel about modifications to partition /dev/fd0p1 -- Invalid argument.  
This means Linux won't know about any changes you made to /dev/fd0p1 until you reboot -- 
so you shouldn't mount it or use it in any way before rebooting.
Error: Failed to add partition 1 (Invalid argument)
```

There's no `/dev/fd0p1` on the machine too. There's the proper `/dev/fd0`.

Note on the Error message: I do get this error message on different Linux systems with different file systems at different occasions from time to time … up to now, I'm not aware of having run into any problems. I won't trust this peace, though

Comment: Could you give the commands you're using to format and mount your floppies? Having partitions on floppies is unusual to say the least!

Comment: @StephenKitt  The reason might be that I had to start `partprobe` to get any response after pushing the Floppy Disk in the machine. So:  `fdformat /dev/fd0` for formatting the floppy, and `mke2fs -t ext2 -T floppy -m 1` for getting an `ext2` Floppy, or `mkkosfs -F 12 -I" for a FAT12 Floppy. Funny thing is, that both systems are Debian Linux based (not Ubuntu!).

Comment: How do you mount them?

Comment: And how do you unmount them?

Answer (score 2):

The key here is that if each drive can read its own disks, but not disks from the other drive, then one or both of them has misaligned heads.  This is a very common problem with floppy drives, especially if they've been dropped.

Essentially it means that one drive is writing the data in the wrong spot, so other drives can't read it.  As the same heads are used for reading and writing, the same drive can read those disks again perfectly well.

Try your disks in other drives if you can, as this will tell you which drive (if any) is correctly aligned.  If disks written in any given drive don't work anywhere else at all, then you know that drive is misaligned.

Realigning a drive is a complicated affair requiring an oscilloscope and special analogue disks that aren't readily available, so replacing the drive is usually the easiest option.